# C# windows phone 8.1 InvokeMember in WebView

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have a URL which have this HTML Code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="http://mySite.ir/search.html" method="POST">
  <input onkeypress=FKeyPress(this); onkeydown=FKeyDown(this); size="25" type="text" name="query" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
  </form>
</html>
```

I want put something on TextBox and press the ClickButton on WebView.
in C# Desktop I've used this code>

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("textBoxV").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pressButton").InvokeMember("submit");
```

but in windows phone 8.1 can't use that method.
please tell me how can I press that button in windows phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call InvokeScriptAsync and call submit on the first form (index == 0) or get the form by id and then call submit().

```
await wview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "var elem = document.forms[0].submit();"});
```

Make sure that the HTML is loaded in your WebView, otherwise this will throw an exception.

Comment: thanks, but how can i set a message into 'textBoxV' ?